# LM324 Pin connections

Tags: arduino, operational-amplifier

I'm trying to wire up the LM324 using only op amp 1 to amplify a 0-5v input to 0-12v scale. I found I need to use a 7/5 ratio for the resistors on my negative feedback loop. I get the theory, I even built the circuit on a simulator and works fine, but I can't seem to hook it up right on my bread board. 
Here's the LM324 Pin Diagram:
[image: LM324 Pin Diagram]
Here's how I've hooked it up right now,

VCC -> +16V. 
GND -> 0v. 
Input 1 +  -> 5v. 
Input 1 - -> 33K-ohm Ressistor -> GND 
Input 1 - (again) -> 47K-ohm Resistor -> Output 1 
then Finally, Output 1 -> LED Strip (Expecting 12 Volts here, but getting nothing).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEAvlh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Disconnect the LED strip and measure the output 1 voltage.  LM324 can't supply unlimited current.

Comment: Have you considered using a transistor instead?

Comment: That's the thing, wouldn't transistor just be either on 12v (16 in this case) or off?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I need it to be scaled up/amplified.

Comment: But... why? You should be using PWM to control brightness, not modifying voltage. And PWM is either full on or full off.

Comment: @markrages I tried it with single leds too. no luck.

Comment: Shello is that how you have it set up?

Comment: Maybe a picture of what you have built will help...

Comment: First off, this opamp is not rail to rail input or output. What this means is that any input that's near the rail (0V) will be clipped. I've used it before and had to find out the hard way. Anyway, any signal below (0.5V?) would be seen as 0.5V. If I'm not mistaken, anything near Vcc-0.5V does the same thing.

Comment: @Passerby yes. Thats exactly how it is. Thank you.

Comment: @shello So - what happens if you disconnect the LEDs and leave the output open as markrages suggests?

Comment: @shello if it's wired just like that, you should have 20~40mA at 12v on that output. A single section of a led strip should work (if you cut if off).

Comment: Are you using a bread board that has holes to push wires into? This invites instability. It's better if you air wire the parts on copper clad which provides a ground plane for return currents. Do you have a decoupling cap on the supply pin to GND?

Answer (score 1):

First, you should clarify what your LED is.  Single LEDs typically have forward voltages around 1-3V, so 12V LED makes me suspect it is either a part designed for automotive use, or  a string of LEDs in series.

If it is an automotive part then it's quite possible it's designed for high current operation and the LM324 can not supply the required current to light the LED.  The LM324 might burn itself up in the attempt.

If it is a string of low-power LEDs then you still have a problem because you need current limiting.  If the component tolerance variation causes the string of LEDs to have a forward voltage of greater than 12V, then they won't light up; if their tolerance causes the forward voltage to be less than 12V they (or the opamp) might burn up without current limiting.